# Change page title in controler or block

Tags: magento2, blocks, controllers, page-title

I have found two ways for changing page title and I don't know which one I should use.

**1. Override `prepareLayout()` in block**

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Title') . ' - ' . $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->getDefault());
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

**2. Change title via `\Magento\Framework\App\ViewInterface` in controller**

in `execute()` method:

```
        $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Downloadable Products'));
```

Comment: Avoid $this->_view. You can use xml or from controller it's your choice

Comment: Ok, do you have any correct way to present it here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it in different ways - it's enough to use only one:

**1. From controller**

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Something');
```

**2. From layout**
**module_controller_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Something..</title>
    </head>
</page>
```

**NOTE - In most cases xml would be loaded first, so take in account that title can be changed in controller**

Comment: I've just encountred something similar for layout:
`<referenceBlock name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Title</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>`

Is it deprecated and I should way you showed?

Comment: You can use any of them.

Comment: It is better to use your way - it is simpler.

Comment: in magento 2 I want to change "Related Products" to something else how can I?

Comment: Another option is to change the original phrase using csv translations

Comment: Hi, this also set title in page-title element. Is there a way we can only set tab title?

Comment: @SohelRana - Is this still working in Magento 2.4.3? I believe I am unable to set block page title from controller or xml file and need to set in phtml as it gives error `Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page::$_view`

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy yes. Still works. Here is the class: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Page/Title.php#L59

Comment: This is giving me same $_view error when used in controller. For this reason I have been unable to dynamically set page title for add and edit user pages using controller in ver 2.4.3
`$resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('User List'));
$this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle('User List');`

Comment: Why you use $this->_view->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle('User List'); @Slimshadddyyy. Remove that

Comment: What snippet you suggest to use in block or controller file to set page title dynamically instead of writing in phtml? For e.g. show text `Add User` and `Edit User - ABC` based on action

Comment: Check the answer for controller.

Comment: This may not work to set `page.main.title` using block method `setPageTitle` that is different from page title (also know as title tag)